# What is lower bound for expected value of sum of iid random variables?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $x_1,…,x_n$ be iid positive random variables where $x_i \in \{1,2,...,k\} $ and $E(x_i)=\mu$, and $\mu$ is unknown, now assume $X=x_1+x_2+...+x_n$, we know from central limit theorem that $E(X)=n \times \mu$, but as i said $\mu$ is unknown, can we have an upper bound or lower bound for $E(X)$?

**Edit**

all of $k$ values for $x_i$ has a chance to be chosen. For example we dont have $Pr(x_i=5)=0$ where $5<k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can we have an upper bound or lower bound for $E(X)$?

Yes, we can!

Clearly $n\leq \mathsf E(X)\leq kn$

> **Edit** all of $k$ values for $x_i$ has a chance to be chosen.

All that tells us is that the extremes are not plausible values of $\mathsf E(X)$, so$$n<\mathsf E(X)<nk$$

Comment: tanks a lot for your answer. lower bound $n$ is exactly what i want, can you give me more Clear proof just for lower bound $n$.

Comment: Because $\mathsf E(X)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{x_i=1}^k x_i\,p(x_i) = \sum\limits_{x=1}^k nx\,p(x)$ where $\sum\limits_{x=1}^kp(x)=1~\wedge~\forall x{\in}\{1,..,k\}:0{<}p(x){<}1$, therefore $n<\mathsf E(X)<nk$ .  That is all. @PayamAbdy  [Or in other words: How can the average be less than the minimum value?]

Comment: i am very grateful.